# Javascript: s/digit/" " x that digit/g

Tags: javascript

I would like to match a digit and replace it with that many spaces. Can this be done in less than 9 lines of code?

Example

```
"asnthsnth4nts4h3n" --> "asnthsnth    nts    h   n"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
"asnthsnth4nts4h3n".replace(/\d+/g, function($0) { return Array(parseInt($0, 10)+1).join(" "); })
```

Comment: Awesome. I didn't know you could do cool perl stuff like that! Thanks.